# How to create a table with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Struggling with a create table statement which is based on this select into statement below:

```
@MaxAPDRefundAmount     money = 13.00 

...

    select pkd.*,  pd.ProviderReference, per.FirstName, per.Surname, @MaxAPDRefundAmount [MaxAPDRefundAmount],commission.Type [Commission] into #StagedData from CTE_PackageData pkd
                        inner join J2H.dbo.Package pk on pkd.Reference = pk.Reference
                        inner join J2H.dbo.Product pd on pk.PackageId = pd.PackageId
                        inner join J2H.dbo.FlightReservation fr on pd.ProductId  = fr.ProductId
                                and fr.FlightBoundID = 1
                        inner join J2H.dbo.ProductPerson pp on pd.ProductId = pp.ProductID
                            and pp.StatusId < 7
                        inner join J2H.dbo.Flight f on fr.FlightId = f.FlightID
                        inner join J2H.dbo.Person per on pk.PackageId = per.PackageId
                                    and per.PersonId = pp.PersonId
                        inner join J2H.dbo.PersonType pt on per.PersonTypeId = pt.PersonTypeID
```

We are changing a select into to just normal insert and select, so need a create table (we are going to create a temp (hash tag table) and not declaring a variable table. Also there is a pkd.* at the start as well so I am confused in knowing which fields to include in the create table. Do I include all the fields in the select statement into the create statement?

Update:

So virtually I know I need to include the data types below but I can just do:

```
create table #StagedData
        (
                pkd.*,  
                pd.ProviderReference, 
                per.FirstName, 
                per.Surname, 
                @MaxAPDRefundAmount [MaxAPDRefundAmount],
                commission
        )
```

Comment: If it's worth doing, it's worth doing well.  Replace `pkd.*` with a list of just the fields you actually need.  You only have to do it once.  Plus it may have taken less time to do that than it did to ask your question.

Comment: If possible (if pkd is not frequently changed), I would only use pkd.id (or whetever unique ID you have in pkd table) in temporary table - you could afterwards always join temp table to pkd. This makes your procedure simpler to maintain, when pkd structure changes and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of the `CREATE TABLE` statement is pretty straightforward.

No.  Clearly, you cannot use `pkd.*` in a `create table` statement.

What you can do is run your old `SELECT INTO` statement as a straight SELECT (remove the `INTO #stagedata`) part, and look at the columns that get returned by the SELECT.

Then write a `CREATE TABLE` statement that includes those columns.

Answer (score 2):

"Do I include all the fields in the select statement into the create statement?" Well, that depends, if you need them, than yes, if not than no. It's impossible for us to say whether you need them... If you're running this exact query as `insert`, than yes.

As for the create statement, you can run the query you have, but replace `into #StagedData` with something like `into TEMP_StagedData`. In management studio you can let sql server build the create query for you: right-click the newly created `TEMP_StagedData` table in the object explorer (remember to refresh), `script Table as`, `CREATE To` and select `New Query Editor Window`.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean with the update. As you say you need datatypes, also, columnnames like `pkd.*` are illegal if not within `[]`, and definitly not recommended. If with `pkd.*` you mean "create columns as in table `pkd`", than no, you can't do that. I'd stick to my original answer, if I were you

Answer (score 0):

To create a table from a SELECT without inserting data, add a WHERE clause that never returns True.

Like this:

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM Table WHERE 1=0
```

Once the table with the columns for your SELECT, you can add additional columns with ALTER TABLE.

```
ALTER TABLE #TempTable ALL ExtraColumn INT
```

Then do your INSERT/SELECT.

Comment: If you look closely, you'll see that's the structure of the query OP already has, he wants to transform it into a `insert into` structure, with the table already present.